# What is the difference between MLT profiles and MLT presets?

Tags: mlt

[MLT profiles](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/profiles/) and [MLT presets](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/presets/)

They're both text files of `thing=thing\n` which apply to an MLT thing, which change how the 'mlt service' works.

And how can I add a new profile? And a new preset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A profile helps set the required properties of the end output. A preset is just a collection of options which can apply to any mlt service.

You can create a new preset by putting the key=value pairs into a file anywhere, then using the absolute path of the file, where you would normally specify a known-preset-name.